# Difference between Git local and remote HEAD

Tags: git

I have been reading and practicing with git. I have a question about the pointer `HEAD`. I understand that it is a special pointer that points to the current branch, but if I do `git branch --all`, all I see is this:

```
* Test_Branch_1
  main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/Test_Branch_1
  remotes/origin/main
```

This makes sense. I can see my remote `main` branch and `HEAD` pointing at it. But I also see a `*` next to `Test_Branch_1` which seems to indicate that `HEAD` is also pointed at `Test_Branch_1`? If I look at my last commit on `Test_Branch_1` by doing `git log -1` I see something like:

```
commit checksum (HEAD -> Test_Branch_1)
Merge: ...
Author: ...
Date: ...
```

Again, `HEAD` appears to be pointing at `Test_Branch_1`. It would appear there is a local and remote version of `HEAD`? The local one keeps track of which branch I am on locally? In this case the local version of `Test_Branch_1`? And the remote version of `HEAD` never changes in practice (i.e., always points at `main`)?

Is that correct or am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: "And the remote version of HEAD never changes in practice (i.e., always points at main)?" Well, no; it points wherever the remote repo says it points. Just to be clear, though: the notion of a remote HEAD is pretty useless and you should probably pretend it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct.

`remotes/origin/HEAD` is a **local** alias for a remote branch.
It points to what you want to be the default branch for `origin` allowing you to use `origin` instead of (for ex.) `origin/main` wherever it makes sense.
You can set/delete it with `git remote set-head origin main` / `git remote set-head -d origin`
Again this has no effects on the remote repository and is not shared with your team mates.

As a side note, because you can have multiple *origins*, you can have multiple `remotes/.../HEAD`.

For more info take a look at the doc of [git remote set-head](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)